# Are Elastic Beanstalk's .ebextension commands run only on server setup?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

The [Elastic Beanstalk documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-commands) says:

> You can use the commands key to execute commands on the EC2 instance. The commands are processed in alphabetical order by name, and they run before the application and web server are set up and the application version file is extracted.

Should I understand that this is only run when the server is first set up, and *not on further deployments*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands in the .ebextensions configuration are executed on *each deployment*. For example, you can stop a Windows Service, reinstall it, and start it again after each deployment (in one command with a batch file or with three separate commands).